# Vue router fails to load child route

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to set up router in my Vue app. Everything seemed to work fine until i started to try implementing children routes. Now when i try to access child route i get an error message along with some warnings:
[What happens when i click on child router-link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePqki.png)

My router setup:

```
const router = createRouter({
history: createWebHistory(),
routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/welcome' },
    {
      name: 'welcome',
      path: '/welcome',
      component: WelcomePage
    },
    {
        name:'noteLists',
        path: '/noteLists',
        component: NoteListLinks,
        children: [
          {
            name:'noteListSheets',
            path: ':id',
            components: FullNoteSheet
          }
        ]
    }
],
linkActiveClass: 'active'
```

});

All other route links work fine.

The components template where child links are used and rendered looks like that:

```
<template>
<router-link 
    :to="setNoteListLink(entry.id)"
    :key=entry.id
    v-for="entry in notesListEntry"
    >
    {{entry.name}}
</router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
```

Function setNoteListLink just creates a links like '/noteList/1'.

The error says that it "Cannot read property 'writeDebug' of undefined" and writeDebug is a method on a component that it tries to load when i click on the route (FullNoteSheet), so i assume there is something wrong with the component and not the router. But component works just fine if i try to load it separately, by jst putting it in App component template.

If you have dealt with such issues and know the solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the `noteListSheets` route; It should be `component: FullNoteSheet` not `components: FullNoteSheet`